# Application failing to start under weblogic (no persistent units parsed from classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic

The other team developed this application while I recently developed two more api on this application according to internal documentation(which is not very clear).

I got the below error message when I try to start the application:
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}

I have not changed this persistence.xml or refer to it, and I have no idea on how to fix it.

Below is the entire stack-trace that resulted from weblogic server when try to start the application.

Stack trace for message 149004 weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml} at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337) at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57) at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360) Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml} at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:722) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.determinePersistenceUnitInfo(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:387) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:332) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292) at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:719) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197) at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1929) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3194) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1877) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:932) at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360) at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337) at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57) at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)

Answer (score -1):

I finally managed to solve the problem by restarting the WebLogic server. Also, please ensure the database config is correct so that the server can be restarted successfully.